# make jquery procedure run better

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('#MyDiv .TheClass').eq(TheIndex).removeClass('ClassA');
$('#MyDiv .TheClass').eq(TheIndex).removeClass('ClassB');
$('#MyDiv .TheClass').eq(TheIndex).addClass('ClassC');

$('#MyDiv .TheClass').eq(TheIndex).children().each(function () {
 //do something here
});
```

It seems I'm using the **$('#MyDiv .TheClass').eq(TheIndex)** line several times; how can I make this better?

I thought of doing

```
var TheDiv = $('#MyDiv .TheClass').eq(TheIndex);

TheDiv.removeClass('ClassA');
TheDiv.removeClass('ClassB');
TheDiv.addClass('ClassC');

TheDiv.children().each(function () {
 //do something here
});
```

But I'm wondering if there's a better suggestion out there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery provides a [*fluent interface* <sup>[Wikipedia]</sup>](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Fluent_interface) with most of its methods:

```
$('#MyDiv .TheClass').eq(TheIndex)
  .removeClass('ClassA ClassB')
  .addClass('ClassC')
  .children().each(function () { 
      // do something here
  });
```

If you are sure that the element has the classes `ClassA` and `ClassB` and needs `ClassC`, you can use [`.toggleClass()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/):

```
$('#MyDiv .TheClass').eq(TheIndex)
  .toggleClass('ClassA ClassB ClassC')
  .children().each(function () {
      // do something here
  });
```

Though not necessarily relevant for your case, but if you wanted to chain more methods after the `each` loop, the following methods would apply to the selected children. If you want to select the original element again (`$('#MyDiv .TheClass').eq(TheIndex)`) you can go "one step back" in the chain by using [`.end()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/end/).

Comment: you can do `.removeClass('ClassA ClassB')`

Comment: Actually, it has either ClassA or ClassB; would toggle still be a good idea. For the moment I'm saying to remove both and that works.

Comment: @frenchie: If it has either of these classes, then stick with `removeClass`. Otherwise it would add the class which is not present.

Comment: Thanks Felix for this precision.